# allocate same memory for one class or changing final variable in java

Tags: java, android, memory-management, allocation

I have a class in android (java) I forced to create that class every second (new className() ) because variable is final . this use a lot of memory .
I can not change the class because it is implemented in  a library

I want :
 when at first create className and OS allocates a memory place, when I create my class again , it replace to that place which allocated at the first time. Or
How I can change final variable?

Comment: use singleton class

Comment: then dont create new instances, instate design your class so that it can mutate!

Comment: What does the class do?  Depending on its responsibilities, you might want to use either a singleton (as @RandykaYudhistira suggested above) or the flyweight design pattern.

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ  I can not chang that class, that class is defined in library

Comment: @Randyka Yudhistira  can you say me how can I use singleton?

Comment: You can't explicitly deallocate memory in Java. If there are no more references to an object it should be automatically garbage collected. If that's not happening, there may be a memory leak in your code or the library you're using.

Comment: it is my problem that when garbage collected automatically , my app became slow

Comment: No idea what you are asking for. If it is "your class", why does it matter that it is in a library? Sorry, but you rather give some code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem:

By this code:

```
Field modifierslatitude = className.class.getDeclaredField("latitude");
modifierslatitude.setAccessible(true);
modifierslatitude.set(classNameObjectThatFirstCreate, location.getLatitude() + MainActivity.y * 0.0002);
```

in fact I changed final variable without create new class again and again

Comment: OMG.  OMG.  OMG.   OMG.  OMG.

Comment: @TelegramInstagram You are a hacker!

Answer (score 1):

Singleton Class example :

```
public class SomeClass {
  private static LibraryClass libraryClass;
  public static LibraryClass getInstance() {
    if(libraryClass == null) {
      libraryClass = new LibraryClass();
    }
    return libraryClass;
  }
}
```

Then you can call it : `LibraryClass libraryClass = SomeClass.getInstance();`

Comment: I want to set a value to final variable in libraryclass and I set value only in constructor, in your example I can not set value to variable

Comment: @TelegramInstagram if that value fixed at the beginning it's trivial to adapt constructor invocation in snippet above. If that value changes, since it's `final`, you cannot reuse the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `reset()` method on your class, which resets all fields of the object to the initial state.

When you want to create a new object, without creating a new object, call `reset()` on old object and re-use it.

Comment: I can not change the class because it is implemented in a library

Comment: @TelegramInstagram, if the class has setters for all fields, you can write a utility method `resetObject(LibObject object)` in your code which calls setters of all fields of the object to reset them to initial value. Then, you can call this method when you want to re-use the object.

Comment: it is my problem taht I can not write(set) method in that class, and variables is final , I can not change class at all .

Comment: @TelegramInstagram, you may be able to set values of private final fields of this object with the method described in following answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301720/1015678

Comment: @LahiruChandima Good point. Does that work on Android too? (I mean the technique to bypass `final` linked in previous comment, not your answer ☺)